# AngularJS Function with ng-if inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some times that are calculated dynamically and repeat in an ng-repeat like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="time in scheduling.openTimes">
   <label class="label label-default label-time" ng-class="{'active' : scheduling.militaryTime == time.military}" ng-click="scheduling.setTime(time.military)" ng-if="!scheduling.booked(time.military)">
        {{time.display}}
</label>
</div>
```

And the function `scheduling.booked()` gets called on each label. It should either return true if the time is "booked" or false if not.

I want the time to display if the time is `NOT BOOKED`. My function looks like so:

```
        scheduling.booked = function(time)
    {
        ref.child('appointments').once('value', function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var data = childSnapshot.val();
                var sysDate = new Date(scheduling.date);
                var appDate = new Date(data.date);
                var appTime = data.time.military;

                if(appDate.getDay() == sysDate.getDay())
                {
                    if(appTime == time)
                    {
                        return true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false
                }
            })
        })

    }
```

It consoles out everything like it should but the label is not hiding? The console shows that is should be.

**update**

through some research and lots of deleting, I've came up with this. It works and does what I want as long as you only have one appointment. If you have more than one, it duplicates the time slot. How would you make it so it checked if the time was in the array already and skip it if it is?

```
scheduling.booked = function(time, timeDis) {

        ref.child('appointments').once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var data = childSnapshot.val();
                var sysDate = new Date(scheduling.date).getDate();
                var appDate = new Date(data.date).getDate();
                var appTime = data.time.military;
                if(sysDate == appDate)
                {
                    if(appTime == time)
                    {
                        $scope.openTimes.push({
                            'military' : time,
                            'display'  : timeDis,
                            'disabled' : true
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.openTimes.push({
                            'military' : time,
                            'display'  : timeDis,
                            'disabled' : false
                        })
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.openTimes.push({
                        'military' : time,
                        'display'  : timeDis,
                        'disabled' : false
                    })
                }

            })
        });

        $timeout(function(){
            scheduling.openTimes = $scope.openTimes;
            scheduling.timeLoading = false;
        }, 1300)

    }
```

I have another function calling this one now, I've ditched the ng-if.

Comment: Can you try once by simple returning true or false inside `scheduling.booked` function, so that we can narrow down the issue?

Comment: Simply returning true using @stanleyxu2005's answer and removing the ref.child()... makes the function work correctly. Same is true with returning false. So it goes back to my suspicion the HTML is resolving prior to the function returning.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `scheduling.booked` does not have a `return`. So it will always return `undefined`. So when angular interprets `ng-if="!scheduling.booked(time.military)"` will be `ng-if="true"` (`!undefined` equals `true`). This explains why all records are shown.

I think the following code  should work.

```
scheduling.booked = function(time) {
  var booked = false;

  ref.child('appointments').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var data = childSnapshot.val();
      var sysDate = new Date(scheduling.date);
      var appDate = new Date(data.date);
      var appTime = data.time.military;

      if (appDate.getDay() == sysDate.getDay() && appTime == time) {
        booked = true;
      }
    })
  });

  return booked; // <-- make sure the function has a return value
}
```

Comment: While cleaner, it's not hiding anything.

Comment: I think it is because the html is resolving before the function returns? Is that possible?

Comment: The function is console logging everything like it should. So... when the time is booked the function is returning true like it should. The label is not hiding though.

Comment: Where do you insert your `console.log`? As I said, your function will return `undefined` on every call. So `ng-if="!scheduling.booked(time.military)` will  be `ng-if="!undefined"`. This explains why all records are shown.

Comment: Right above `return booked;` and it needs to return either true or false to either show the time or hide it. How complicated can it be?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not complicated, but your function `scheduling.booked` does not use `return`. It will always return `undefined`. How can this function return true or false? Please show me the magic ;-)

Comment: Check my updated question for my solution. It presents it's own issue. Maybe this one will be simpler.